# Escape < in xml node

Tags: xml, parsing

i'm reading a xml in php but i've got an error on the parse:

> Warning: simplexml_load_string() [function.simplexml-load-string]:
>   Entity: line 5: parser error : error parsing attribute name

my xml string is:

```
$xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messages>
<message>
  <date>1352210570</date>
  <from>Rui <rui@mail.pt></from>
  <subject>Mensagem de Teste</subject>
  <url>test.com</url>
</message>
</messages>';
```

i parse the xml with simplexml_load_string($xmlString);

how can i escape the < and > on the from node??

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091945/where-can-i-get-a-list-of-the-xml-document-escape-characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$xmlString = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<messages>
<message>
  <date>1352210570</date>
  <from><![CDATA[Rui <rui@mail.pt>]]></from>
  <subject>Mensagem de Teste</subject>
  <url>test.com</url>
</message>
</messages>';
```

The addition to your code was the inclusion of `<![CDATA[` after your `<from>` tag and a `]]>` before your `</from>` tag.

Note that within the CDATA tag, there is no quotes to denote a string.  This tripped me up initially, so I'm trying to make sure it doesn't happen to others.

While `&lt;` and `&gt;` are probably a bit speedier in terms of performance, if you're writing potentially dynamic XML strings, The `<![CDATA[someText]]>` is much more of a "blanket escape"

Comment: Jon but i received the xml with the < and >. how can i replace the < and > only from the from node??

Comment: How are you generating this string (Language, pseudocode) (Which is input for simplexml_load_string(), I'm assuming)

Comment: @xmatzx — You don't have XML. Reject it and tell whomever sent it to you to send XML instead.